# getStaticProps returning an undefined result

Tags: next.js

I believe the codebase must be setup wrong but I cannot determine what convention I'm not following with getStaticProps on next js

[Link to codesandbox.io project](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/pythonpadawanEXE/nextjs-blog/main?file=%2FREADME.md&workspace=%257B%2522activeFilepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpages%252Findex.js%2522%252C%2522openFiles%2522%253A%255B%2522%252FREADME.md%2522%255D%252C%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522gitSidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522COMMIT%2522%252C%2522spaces%2522%253A%257B%2522clgiqz4og000x2a6ezvp08zeh%2522%253A%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clgiqz4og000x2a6ezvp08zeh%2522%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522Default%2522%252C%2522devtools%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clgj0g322000x2a6ebspk5ycz%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PROJECT_SETUP%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PREVIEW%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A3000%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clgiqz8hl006e2a6eewqu8w8s%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522dev%2522%252C%2522key%2522%253A%2522clgiqz7eo003t2a6etzvm3ten%2522%252C%2522isMinimized%2522%253Afalse%257D%255D%257D%252C%2522clgj0eu5u00852a6ecz66otjp%2522%253A%257B%2522key%2522%253A%2522clgj0eu5u00852a6ecz66otjp%2522%252C%2522devtools%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522name%2522%253A%2522New%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522currentSpace%2522%253A%2522clgiqz4og000x2a6ezvp08zeh%2522%252C%2522spacesOrder%2522%253A%255B%2522clgiqz4og000x2a6ezvp08zeh%2522%252C%2522clgj0eu5u00852a6ecz66otjp%2522%255D%252C%2522hideCodeEditor%2522%253Afalse%257D)

```
// Page Component, receiving allPokemons
// from getStaticProps
export default function Home({ allPokemons }) {
  return (
      <ul>
          { /* mapping all the data inside
          an unordered list */}
          {allPokemons.map((poke) => (
              <li key={poke.url}>{poke.name}</li>
          ))}
      </ul>
  );
}

export async function getStaticProps() {

  // Call the fetch method and passing
  // the pokeAPI link
  const response = await fetch(
      'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/');

  // Parse the JSON
  const data = await response.json();

  // Finally we return the result
  // inside props as allPokemons
  return {
      props: { allPokemons: data.results },
  };
}
```

[image]

I was expecting this to produce a list of pokemon per this
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-js-getstaticprops-function/

Comment: The code above seems fine, the codesandbox is private so I can't see your config.

Comment: Use axios in client instead

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the _app.js file disables getStaticProps from working, by removing this file from the file structure the getStaticProps function could now work.
https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).